# ghostScript Crop pdf to thumbnail in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, png, ghostscript

I want to covert PDF to thumbnail of 185x185 size. I am using cropBox option of ghostScript to crop this PDF. But it is creating a thumbnail from left bottom side of of PDF.

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=png16m -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage=true -g185x185 -dUseCropBox= true -sOutputFile= + thumbFullPath+ "' '" + sourceFileCompletePath
```

How should i make sure that pdf thumbnail is cropped from upper left corner??

Also some times, some thumbnails are turning sides away.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The PostScript and PDF co-ordinate systems have 0,0 at the bottom left corner which is why they begin drawing there. So in order to have the top left corner of the PDF content be at the top left of the resulting image, you would have to translate the co-ordinate system down by an 'appropriate' amount.

Appropriate in this case depends on knowing the size of the page and calculating the amount of the page which will be rendered into your thumbnail, then using the 'translate' operator to move the origin so that the top left of the rendered image is co-incident with the top left of the page.

However, I suspect that this isn't actually what you are trying to achieve. As with your previous question, an example file would be useful.

Comment: hmmm yes... Can you please refer some references to read more about ghostScript PDF to thumbnail generation which will give me basic knowledge about ghostScript. I'm searching it for a long but didn't find anything good.

Comment: Basically What i want is convert PDF to 185X185 pixels thumbnail.

Comment: imagemagick/rmagick provides an option `resize_to_fill` to covert full PDF page to given size. Is there any option in ghostscript that gives same functionality?? So that my pdf page can be filled into given ppixel size thumbnail

Comment: There is no single control which will do this, but the effect can definitely be achieved. However, without seein example files to show your problems, I really can't give you a prescription, which is what you seem to want. As far as references, you can read the Ghostscript documentation, the PDF Reference Manual, and the PostScript Language Reference Manual.

Comment: I ave updated my question. This is how image is getting turned sides away. and also it is not being croped in 185X185 pixel

Comment: When I say I need to see an example file, I mean I need to see the *source* file, not the result....

Comment: The source input file, the PDF or PostScript program